# Recycler view hidden and only visible if EditText below is clicked

Tags: java, android

I'm having an issue with my recycler view, when you first load the app, it is hidden like the image below:

[image]

But when I click the Edit text below it, it becomes visible like the image below:

[image]

Is there any way I can fix this? so that it is always visible?

here is my code for the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".FoodItemPage"

    >

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".FoodItemPage">


        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/food_items"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:cardElevation="5dp"
                    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/food_price_layout"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/food_name1"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:paddingLeft="12dp"
                                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                                android:text="Food Name"
                                android:textColor="@color/btnSignUp"
                                android:textSize="20sp"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/food_description"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:maxLength="150"
                                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                                android:text=" description goes here"
                                android:textColor="@android:color/secondary_text_light"
                                android:textSize="18dp" />

                        </LinearLayout>




                    </LinearLayout>
                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/food_sizes"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="12dp"

                    android:text="Choose Size"
                    android:textColor="@color/btnSignUp"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:maxLength="150"
                    android:maxLines="4"
                    android:paddingLeft="12dp"
                    android:text="Required"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/secondary_text_light"
                    android:textSize="14dp" />

                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:cardElevation="5dp"
                    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical">


                        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                            android:id="@+id/size_recycler"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:paddingLeft="12dp"></androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>


                    </LinearLayout>
                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/food_extras"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="12dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                    android:text="Extras"
                    android:textColor="@color/btnSignUp"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:cardElevation="5dp"
                    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical">




                        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                            android:id="@+id/extras_recycler"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:paddingLeft="12dp"></androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>


                    </LinearLayout>
                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:cardElevation="5dp"
                    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/extra_notes"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:hint="i.e. Make it super spicy" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/extra_notes_title"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:paddingLeft="12dp"
                            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                            android:text="Extra Notes"
                            android:textColor="@color/btnSignUp"
                            android:textSize="15sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />


                    </LinearLayout>
                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:elevation="5dp"
                    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
                    >
                    >

                    <com.cepheuen.elegantnumberbutton.view.ElegantNumberButton
                        android:id="@+id/number_button"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="90dp"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        app:backGroundColor="@color/btnSignUp"
                        app:finalNumber="20"
                        app:initialNumber="1"
                        app:textSize="8sp" />


                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:contentScrim="#0e0d0e"
                app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">



            </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/btnSignUp"

        >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/addToCart"
            android:text="ADD TO CART"
            android:background="@color/btnSignUp"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and my code for the activity

```
public class FoodItemPage extends AppCompatActivity {


    private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    private FoodExtrasAdapter extrasAdapter;


    ElegantNumberButton number_button;
    Button addtocart;
    TextView food_name, food_description;
    EditText extra_notes;

    String foodId;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_food_item_page);

        //init view
        number_button = (ElegantNumberButton) findViewById(R.id.number_button);
        addtocart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addToCart);
        food_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.food_name1);
        food_description = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.food_description);

        setUpFoodInfo();

        setUpExtras();

        setUpSizes();


    }

    private void setUpFoodInfo() {

        foodId = getIntent().getStringExtra("foodid");
        //firestore
        Query singlefoodref = db.collectionGroup("Foods").whereEqualTo("id", foodId);

        singlefoodref.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {

                if (queryDocumentSnapshots != null) {
                    SelectedFoodModel selectedFoodModel = queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments().get(0).toObject(SelectedFoodModel.class);
                    food_name.setText(selectedFoodModel.getName());
                    food_description.setText(selectedFoodModel.getDescription());

                    Log.d(TAG, "WORKING");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void setUpSizes() {
        if (getIntent() != null)
            foodId = getIntent().getStringExtra("foodid");
        if (!foodId.isEmpty() && foodId != null) {
            Query foodSizes = db.collectionGroup("sizes").whereEqualTo("id", foodId);


        }

    }

    private void setUpExtras() {
        if (getIntent() != null)
            foodId = getIntent().getStringExtra("foodid");
        if (!foodId.isEmpty() && foodId != null) {
            Query foodExtras = db.collectionGroup("extras").whereEqualTo("id", foodId).orderBy("price");

            FirestoreRecyclerOptions<ExtrasModel> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<ExtrasModel>()
                    .setQuery(foodExtras, ExtrasModel.class)
                    .build();

            extrasAdapter = new FoodExtrasAdapter(options);

            RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.extras_recycler);
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
            recyclerView.setAdapter(extrasAdapter);

            Log.d(TAG, "LOADED  " + foodId);


        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        extrasAdapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        extrasAdapter.stopListening();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

fixed it,  all i had to do was remove the collapsing toolbar layout.

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:contentScrim="#0e0d0e"
                app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
```